# twitter API with MonoDevelop and C#

Tags: c#, twitter, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, json.net

i m working with MonoDevelop. I tried using Twitterizer, as well as tweetsharp but both gives error.
My MonoDevelop version is 2.8.2. When the application launches i get the following error.

> Could not load 'Newtonsoft.Json' for registration. This could be due to an outdated assembly kept by the simulator, location: 
>   /Users/apple/Projects/test/test/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/Newtonsoft.Json.dll

And when i try to access the Twitter api i get the following error

> Could not load type 'System.Diagnostics.Trace' from assembly 'Hammock'.

Comment: Just a thought but isn't whats provided with iOS 5 sufficient for your twitter requirements?

Answer (score 4):

> Could not load 'Newtonsoft.Json' for registration. This could be due to an outdated assembly kept by the simulator

Your first error message makes me think you're using MonoTouch, right ?

If so then you cannot use **Newtonsoft.Json.dll** as is. This assembly requires some features that are not possible on iOS devices (e.g. dynamic runtime code generation).

There is a special **[Newtonsoft.Json.MonoTouch.dll](https://github.com/chrisntr/Newtonsoft.Json)** version that you can use. Make sure to build it from the latest sources to get all the fixes.

> i get the following error Could not load type 'System.Diagnostics.Trace' from assembly 'Hammock'.

Also you cannot (in general) re-use assemblies compiled with a different framework version since it can include types that are not available in MonoTouch base class library. To avoid this you should build your code from source or find a MonoTouch-ready assembly.

Comment: Andrew Young has a more recent version of JSON.NET which I've updated recently to be compatible with MD 2.8 and MT 5.x: https://github.com/ayoung/Newtonsoft.Json. For Hammock you will need to build from source using the MT project in this repo: https://github.com/danielcrenna/hammock

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.
Yes i am using monotouch. Also, i had done as you said, dowloaded the HAMMOCK, and NEWTONSOFT.JSON projects, compiled and used these dlls along with my Tweetsharp dlls. But when i open the Tweetsharp.dll in the assembly editor, i can see an error which says "Couldn't load HAMMOCK.dll" and "Couldn't load NEWTONSOFT.JSON.dll" 
I believe Tweetsharp.dll is unable to recognize the dlls HAMMOCK and NEWTONSOFT.JSON, is there anything wrong with the TweetSharp.dll? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You'll have to rebuild `TweetSharp.dll` (**and** any other assemblies that depends on code you re-compiled) to ensure all references are correct.